# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseUser

Tags: android, parse-platform

A quick overview of the app: The user selects a single friend from the list, which is displayed in a Spinner. After the message is typed, the user clicks on the send button. And this is where the app breaks down.

This is the relevant output from the logcat:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseUser
            at com.teamtreehouse.ribbit.SMSActivity.createMessage(SMSActivity.java:113)
            at com.teamtreehouse.ribbit.SMSActivity$1.onClick(SMSActivity.java:49)

This is the relevant code:

```
ParseUser RecipientName = (ParseUser)friendsList.getSelectedItem();

// some other code

ParseObject message = new ParseObject(ParseConstants.CLASS_SMS);
message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME, RecipientName.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
//some other code
```

Any ideas?

The entire code for completeness:

```
public class SMSActivity extends Activity {
   protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
   protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;
   protected List<ParseUser> mFriends;
   protected Button sendButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_message_button);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ParseObject message = createMessage();
            if (message == null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SMSActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.error_sending_file).
                setTitle(R.string.general_error).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else {
                send(message);
            }
            finish();
        }
    });

    mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);

    //get a list of all the friends of the user
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = mFriendsRelation.getQuery();
    query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {


            if (e == null) {
                mFriends = friends;

                String[] usernames = new String[mFriends.size()];
                int i = 0;
                for (ParseUser user : mFriends) {
                    usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                    i++;
                }

                //attach the friendlist to the spinner
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        SMSActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        usernames);

                Spinner friendsList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
                friendsList.setAdapter(adapter);



            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SMSActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                        .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }

        }
    });
}

protected ParseObject createMessage() {
    EditText messageView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message_body);
    String messageContent = messageView.getText().toString();

    Spinner friendsList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.friends_list);

    ParseUser RecipientName = (ParseUser)friendsList.getSelectedItem();




    ParseObject message = new ParseObject(ParseConstants.CLASS_SMS);
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME, RecipientName.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS,
            ((ParseUser) friendsList.getSelectedItem()).getObjectId());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SMS, messageContent);

    return message;
}

protected void send(ParseObject message) {
    message.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //success
                Toast.makeText(SMSActivity.this, R.string.success_message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

            else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SMSActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                        .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }


        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: What it type of `friendsList`?

Comment: It's a spinner,  Spinner friendsList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
                friendsList.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: You can't do it. The `Spinner.getSelectedItem()` is a string. You have to first create `ParseUser` object and then only you have to add it to the `ParseObject`.

Comment: So if I cant cast 'Spinner.getSelectedItem()' as a ParseUser, how do I go about it? Are you suggesting to get rid of the Spinner altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a `Map <String,ParseUser> map = new HashMap<String,ParseUser>()`...here you can fill this map.like

```
for (ParseUser user : mFriends) {
                    usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                    map.put(user.getUsername(),user);
                    i++;
                }
```

now get it like:

```
ParseUser RecipientName = map.get(friendsList.getSelectedItem());
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Bless you (: